# Kendo ui comboBox not scrollable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

My Kendo ui drop down is corupted in its look and feel
It does not show scroll bar.
Here is how I am defining and using it (using angularJS)

HTML:

```
<kendo-combo-box
ng-init="productFindCtrl.init()"
   k-data-source="productFindCtrl.getProductsDS()"
   k-data-text-field="'productId'"
   k-data-value-field="'productId'"  
   k-min-length="3"
   k-filter="'startswith'"
   k-select="productFindCtrl.selectProduct"
   style="width: 55%">
</kendo-combo-box>
```

Javascript code (for controller)

```
controller: function($scope, $http){
        var instance = this;
        
        this.init = function () {                
            $http.get("http://theUrlToResourceGoesHere?param=value").then(                    
                function (response) {
                    //SUCCESS
                    console.log("SUCCESSFUL FOR PRODUCTS") ;
                    instance.products = response.data.products;
                    instance.metadata = response.data.metadata;
                    
                    console.log("Products: "+instance.products) ;                       
                },
                function (response) {
                    console.log("ERROR LOADING JSON DATA") ;
                });
         
        }; //end of productFindCtrl.init()
        
        //get productsDS
        this.getProductsDS = function(){
            return instance.products;
        }
    },
```

The result is a messy drop down / combobox.  I get the same problem trying to use either widget.

[image]

But, when I look at the samples, they do exactly the same things and they have a very properly looking drop downs, etc... What's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened to me and I had all the required CSS and such. I fixed it by adding:

```
.k-list-scroller {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

to my CSS file.

The problem is that this code is not defined in `kendo.common.css`, which is the default css file, but defined in `kendo.common-material.css` which you have to use only if you want to use Material or Material Black themes.

Comment: Thanks.  It actually worked for me, overriding .k-list-container styles.  I figured it out by "inspecting" elements.  I am a beginner with the whole concept of html5 and such, so terminology was my problems.

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure the Kendo UI JavaScript and CSS files are from the same version.
- If this is true, try removing non-Kendo UI CSS styles from the page to check for CSS conflicts.
- Make sure the page has a DOCTYPE and the browser displays it in Standards mode, not Quirks mode.